# I have many radio button (more than 200)

Tags: jquery, html

I got a problem, when I have 200 checkbox, I can select one of 200 checkbox and then all chekbox is 'checked', but I needed it with radio button and isn't working for me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/img_pulpitrock.jpg" alt="Pulpit Rock" width="284" height="213"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="aa" id="te" onclick="alertsm()"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="bb" class="qq"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="bb" class="qq"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="bb" class="qq"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="bb" class="qq"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="bb" class="qq"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="bb" class="qq"><br>
<script>
function alertsm(){
    if($("#te").is(':checked')){
        $('.qq').prop("checked", true);
    }else{
        $('.qq').prop("checked", false);

    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my code for checkbox,

[source code](https://pastebin.com/raw/9DAthGk2)

Comment: What you are saying is, when I tick a radio button, all radio button should also be ticked?

Comment: You can't check *all* radio btn with the same name.

Comment: Stick with checkboxes

Comment: Stick with check boxes as pointed out in earlier comments . the name of the check boxes have to be different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/img_pulpitrock.jpg" alt="Pulpit Rock" width="284" height="213"><br>

  <input class="sel" type="radio" value="" name="">Selector<br>
  <input class="qq" type="checkbox" value="" name="a"><br>
  <input class="qq" type="checkbox" value="" name="a"><br>
  <input class="qq" type="checkbox" value="" name="a"><br>


  <script>
    var x=0;


    $( ".sel" ).click(function() {
      if (x==0) {
        x=1;
        alertsm();
      }else{
        x=0;
        alertsm();
      }
    });

    $(".qq").change(function(){
      if ($('.qq:checked').length == $('.qq').length) {
        $('.sel').prop("checked", true);
      } else {
        $('.sel').prop("checked", false);
      }
    });

    function alertsm(){
      if (x==1) {
        $('.qq').prop("checked", true);
      } else {
        if (x==0) {
          $('.qq').prop("checked", false);
          $('.sel').prop("checked", false);
        }
      }
    }


  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to change the menu with radio button, just change the `type` of `class="qq"` into radio. Should be like this

```
<input class="qq" type="radio" value="" name=""><br>
```

Here i will explain the logic, look at this JQuery:

```
$( ".sel" ).click(function() {
  if (x==0) {
    x=1;
    alertsm();
  }else{
    x=0;
    alertsm();
  }
});
```

***Logic of the main query:***

1. Once you click the `class="sel"` then it will check the value of x.
2. Because the value of x is 0 (set by default when declaring var x as 0), it will assign x with 1
3. Then it will run your alertsm() function.

***Additional query***

The main function of this query is: to check whether all of the checkboxes are checked or unchecked.

```
$(".qq").change(function(){
  if ($('.qq:checked').length == $('.qq').length) {
    $('.sel').prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $('.sel').prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

***Logic of the query***

- if all checkboxes are checked, set the status of `class="sel"` into checked
- else, the status of `class="sel"` will be set into unchecked.

Have a try and feel free to ask!

Comment: @سلطان you may check this and mark this as answered.